# Is there a way to provide default context to i18next instance?

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

Regarding to selected gender of user, I need to add context to all calls of i18next.t(). Is there a way to set default context for i18next instance?

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: For example, I want to provide different translations when user select gender in account section, so instead of provide context every time, I want to have something like: i18next({defaultContext: 'male'}).t()

Comment: This is not possible, but you can use the default key (without any _context suffix): https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/context